# FirebaseError: [code=resource-exhausted]: Too many outstanding requests

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection of size >1000 documents , in each document a uid is stored which is used in getting data from other collection. The other collection has further subcollections. I am pushing the object of data into an array . here is the code

```
let arr =[];
let db = firebase.firestore();
 db.collection('Collection1').orderBy('timestamp','desc').onSnapshot(snapshot=>{
snapshot.forEach(async doc=>{
let obj = doc.data();
let uid = obj.uid;
let objM ={}
let obj2={}
let obj3 ={}
 await  db.collection('Collection2').doc(uid).get().then(docs=>{
obj2 = docs.data()

}).then(async ()=>{
 await db.collection('Collection2').doc(uid).collection('subcollection1').doc(uid).get().then(docs=>{
 obj3 = docs.data()

}).then(async ()=>{
await  db.collection('Collection2').doc(uid).collection('subcollection2').doc(uid).get().then(docs=>{
 obj4 = docs.data()

}).then(()=>{
objM={...obj,...obj2,...obj3,...obj4}
arr.push(objM)
}
})
})
})
```

the above code works fine but very slow when Collection1 is of small size, also it gives following error when collection's size is increased

```
Using maximum backoff delay to prevent overloading the backend.
```

and

```
Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Too many outstanding requests.
```

how can i remove the error and also reduce the loading time.

Comment: could you explain more the relationship between the collections and what your update is affecting?  this is because the behavior seems to be a suboptimal architecture so I would like to understand better the issue to be able to understand if this is the cause

Comment: @SoniSol Collection1 stores uid of users those who like the video along with a timestamp, now the userdata is stored in Collection2 and its subcollection, it is accessed using the uid stored in Collection1 . I am pushing the data in an array to be displayed in a table

Comment: Did you find any solution for this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @InaaraKalani well you have to either optimise your query iteration i.e using  proper async await for all firebase queries and instead of using foreach , using for....of   , or the best thing that can be done is to paginate the query which  saves you  from too much useless reads operation